# Unexpected result with Floating Point Values inside of Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

The expected return is shown below:

checkCashRegister(3.26, 100.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]) **should return** [["TWENTY", 60.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["FIVE", 15.00], ["ONE", 1.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.04]].

When I look at the output in the console, it seems the same as expected output, but I don't know the reason it fails. I will appreciate your help. Here is the link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/do91m6qy/

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change;
  // Here is your change, ma'am.
  change="Insufficient Funds";
  change="Closed";
  var typeObj={"PENNY":0.01,"NICKEL":0.05,"DIME":0.10,"QUARTER":0.25,"ONE":1,"FIVE":5,"TEN":10,"TWENTY":20,"ONE HUNDRED":100};
  var changeArr=[["PENNY", 0],["NICKEL", 0],["DIME", 0],["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY",0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]];
  
  var diff=cash-price;
  var total=cid.reduce(function(acc,val){
    //console.log("acc",acc,"val",val);
    return Math.round((acc+val[1])*100)/100;
  },0); 
  //console.log("total",total);
  if(diff>total)
   return "Insufficient Funds";
  else if(diff==total)
   return "Closed";
  
  cid.reverse().forEach(function(arr,i){
   var key=arr[1];
    var curr=typeObj[arr[0]];
    var sum=0;
    diff=Math.round(diff*100)/100;
    console.log("curr",curr,"key",key,"diff",diff,"diff/curr",diff/curr);
    //console.log("changeArr[changeArr.length-1-i][1]",changeArr[changeArr.length-1-i][1]);
   while(key>=curr && (diff/curr>=1)){
        diff=Math.round(diff*100)/100;
 console.log("inside","curr",curr,"key",key,"diff",diff,"diff/curr",diff/curr);       sum+=curr;
       changeArr[changeArr.length-1-i][1]=sum/100*100;
       key-=curr;
       if(diff>=curr) 
         diff-=curr;
    }
  });
    console.log("changeArr",changeArr);

  changeArr=changeArr.filter(function(arr){
    return arr[1]!==0;
  });
  
  console.log(changeArr);
  if(diff===0)
   return changeArr;
  
  
  console.log("------");
  return "Insufficient Funds";
}

// Example cash-in-drawer array:
// [["PENNY", 1.01],
// ["NICKEL", 2.05],
// ["DIME", 3.10],
// ["QUARTER", 4.25],
// ["ONE", 90.00],
// ["FIVE", 55.00],
// ["TEN", 20.00],
// ["TWENTY", 60.00],
// ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]

checkCashRegister(3.26, 100.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]);
```

Comment: I tried fixing the question format to make to readable but I simply couldn't. I'm not fully sure of what your question is but if you get a completely different data structure it cannot be a floating point math issue.

Comment: "When I look at the output in the console, it seems the same as expected output, but I don't know the reason it fails." — If the output is the same as the expected output … why do you think it fails?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry very new in stackoverflow, the issue is solved no problem

Answer (score 0):

The test was failing just because of the array order which was in reverse. So all I had to do was to use array.reverse() and the issue was resolved.